If I "contact support", who do I actually contact?

If I submit this, do I reach the mods of this site, or Stack Exchange staff? If this reaches SE staff, can I get a private chat room with Academia.SE mods?

You reach Stack Exchange staff.
If you want private chat room with the mods, this can be arranged. I recommend to use a flag (which can only be seen by mods) and give us some detail what you need to talk about. However, since this takes some effort, this should be an exception: We won’t be doing this for somebody with little activity in this community or frequently (although once a room is created, it can be re-used indefinitely).
Mind that whenever I refer to something only being accessible by mods, staff may access it as well.
